# span lang="en-gb" gets generated after copying text

Tags: html, lang

I copy a text from a source in a platform. It is a private platform that has a box where you can type text. There is a button where you can see the HTML source code afterwards. I copied numerous texts with no problem. When I am trying to copy-paste the above, I noticed that in the HTML code a specific tag gets produced.

```
<p><strong><em><span lang="en-gb">Week of the 5th&nbsp;of September</span></em></strong></p>
```

So, my question is, how is that possible. Does a text after copying it generates specific tags? So, in the copying process, some things get copied apart from the text we can see... Also, this could be happening because the source text (that is about to be copied) contains characters that are not supported from the unicode set up in the platform (web application)?

I am really curious to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact you said it had a button where you can view source, this sounds like a WYSIWIG (What you see is what you get) editor like CKeditor, TinyMCE, Froala, etc. They take standard HTML textarea elements and using Javascript and CSS convert them into more robust editors.  They allow you to do simple text formatting in the textarea, upload images, view source, etc.

They are used a lot in blogs and for content editing for people that don't write code but want to be able to manage and maintain content in web sites.  For instance if you type a "paragraph" of text in one of these it will automatically wrap it with the appropriate `<p>` tags using Javascript.

In your case you're adding content in this box, and it's simply applying the formatting to it with Javascript.  It will do the same if you just type in the box, vs. copy/paste.

Here are some links to WYSIWIG editors so you can learn more about how they function:

http://ckeditor.com/
https://www.tinymce.com/
https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor

Fun Fact: The editor you used when you typed your question on Stack Overflow uses one of these. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor

Comment: Fantastic mate. The thing is that I might copy the same text to MS Word and then copy it again from there. I do not get the "span lang" tags now. Why is that happening? I understand what you are saying but it must be related to the source as well. The copy from the source generates somethings that then gets the WYSIWIG product the tags (lang etc).

Comment: Word has it's own mechanisms for formatting things you type/paste into it.  And typically when you copy text from Word, you're picking up the Word formatting, and these WYSIWIG editors often times try to replicate that formatting when you paste it.  So if you copy from one source and go directly to ckeditor to paste it, it's going to turn out different, than if you pasted it first into word, copied from there and pasted to ckeditor due to word formatting.  CKeditor (I think) even has a 'paste from word' button.

Answer (score 1):

It`s not much information, so I‘ll take a guess:

For `<strong><em>`: The website could eventually use a div with the `contenteditable="true"` attribute ([more info on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)) as the input method. When you then paste in text from another application that already has markup like bold or italic, it‘s converted to html tags.

The `<span lang="en-gb">` could come from the browser, another application or the website through analyzing the text and adding this.

Comment: I get this even for non bold sentences. Thanks for replying though!